# webview cannot load html file from sd card

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to load a html file from sd-card. Note:
 -> if i load http://www.google.com it works.
 -> the file exists
 -> i have permissions for internet and  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    webComp = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webC);

    WebSettings webSettings = webComp.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        

    webComp.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());                    



    webComp.loadUrl("/sdcard/FMS/1/message.html");            



}
```

Thank you ! :)

Comment: What error do you get, when you use LogCat? What about "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"? I always used sth. like Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/FMS/1/message.html". I'm wondering if its possible to load a HTML file from the storage using the loadUrl method. Maybe you should try a workaround with loadData(...)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Misca,

You shouldn't hard code the directory of the sdcard like that.  Its typically at `/mnt/sdcard/` but this is never assured.  You should also always check if the sdcard exists and is mounted first!

You want to use the following:

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
} else {
    webComp.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FMS/1/message.html");
}
```

Comment: it is downloading only html files. what if html file contains relative paths for loading images and scripts.

Comment: You should notice that the app should have permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 1):

I think the url is file:///sdcard/FMS/1/message.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this, any files local to the .html file will be able to be loaded except for video

```
webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapprepository/index.html");
```