# Force Close on showing Error Page

Tags: android, webview

I am using this guide to show custom error page in my app when there is no Internet network in a fragment,

https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/22207785/how-to-load-custom-error-page-in-webview-when-internet-not-available

but the app force closes when no network, this happens only when I show error page..

without that app starts but I cannot display the error page

Comment: please add your code so we can review what have you done :)

Comment: Please show the logcat and code

Comment: code is same from the above link

Comment: This code is working... In activity show as answer.... But what you do in frament

Comment: i use this
 if (haveNetworkConnection()){
  webview.loadUrl("http://example.org/");
  }
works fine but
 if (haveNetworkConnection()){
  webview.loadUrl("http://example.org/");
  }
  else
  {
   webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
  }
app crashes