# webview not loading custom html

Tags: java, android, webview

Im trying to load custom html page when device lost internet connection or some other errors like with permission and so on. It is showing default android webview page ***Webpage not available net:ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED*** but when i try to load blank page in method bellow like: ***view.loadUrl("about:blank");*** it will load properly and show only blank page.. so why its not loading my custom html page?

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            Log.w("Error code ", String.valueOf(errorCode));
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/blocked.html");
        
        }
    });
```

when i try to call this html as main page outside of above method its working

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/blocked.html");
```

Comment: Have you already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207785/how-to-load-custom-error-page-in-webview-when-internet-not-available), maybe it will help you?

Comment: i updated my question .. i was looking on it but it is not what im looking for.. i want to handle all errors not only with no connection.

Comment: I tried generating that at my end. But, it worked just fine. 1) So I would like to know if your `assets` folder is at right place. Inside `main` on the same level as `java` & `res`. 2) Can you please post the  `blocked.html` code in your question?